# matplotlib windows 10 old looking plot window

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib

I have python 2.7.14 on Win10, and installed matplotlib 2.1.2 via pip. I don't like the way the buttons and the whole plot window look like. How can I fix this. It should rather look like in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZNJI.jpg).

[supposed to be plot window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZNJI.jpg)

[my plot window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEG5z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of matplotlib version >= 2.0 using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.gca()
plt.show()
```

you get this window now:

[image]

You can use the classic style (`plt.style.use("classic")`) to get the old figure style back:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("classic")
plt.gca()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The buttons however are now still different.

In order to change the buttons, you could locate the folder with the buttons,

```
<path to python>\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
```

and replace the images in it with the images of your choice. E.g. you might want to download an [older matplotlib version](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/releases/tag/v1.5.3) and take the images from there.

Comment: Now I got it, thanks! The version was the problem. I was used to 1.5.1. The plots in my project also looked much worse in 2.1.2. `plt.style.use("classic")` made them look the old way. However, I switched back to version 1.5.1 for now. Maybe later I'll find some time to adjust my project to the new version...